# How many distinct Boolean operators are there that take three inputs?

Tags: computer-science

From what I know, boolean operators are the likes of AND, OR, XOR, NOT, NAND and NOR. So does this mean that there are actually 6 distinct boolean operators that can take three inputs?

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each operation you've listed takes *two* inputs, not three. Moreover, you've missed two: the "YES" operator (always outputs "true") and the "NO" operator (always outputs false).

Can you show that these are all the Boolean operations on two inputs that there are? HINT: Can you identify each Boolean operation on two inputs with a function from a four-element set to a two-element set? If so, how many of those are there?

This example should also suggest the general formula for how many Boolean operations of a given arity there are.